# Geosynchronous satellites with polar orbit?

Tags: orbital-motion, satellites

I know that satellites can go in polar orbits, but as far as I have read, this is only done by LEO satellites. I think it is possible to have geosynchronous satellites with polar orbits (near polar), but how feasible is it? I'm wrong?

PD: English is not my native language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geo *synchronous*, yes. Geo *stationary*, No.

"Geosynchronous" means that the orbital period is the same as Earth's rotational period. "Geostationary" means that the satellite always stays directly above the same spot on Earth's surface. You can have a geosynchronous orbit in any plane and with any eccentricity, but a geostationary orbit is only possible if the orbit is circular, and in the plane of the Earth's equator.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Solomon Slow said, the only way to have a geo*stationary* orbit is if you orbit the Earth at exactly the speed that it rotates, so that you "float" about a single point on the surface. Since the Earth rotates on its axis, this is not possible if you are orbiting on a plane perpendicular to the plane of rotation (a polar orbit).

As you said, you can have a geo*synchronous* orbit, so that as you orbit around the poles, you'll be flying above the same exact points at the same times each day.

You *cannot* orbit so that you're just indefinitely "floating" above, say, the North pole.